# Speaking software using C#.net?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, voice

Can someone please teach me how to create C# code that would allow my computer to speak english words that would be base on text provided by the system

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  Are you trying to do text-to-speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use this code of mine.

```
public static class Melodie
{
    private static SpeechLib.SpVoice WomenAgent = new SpeechLib.SpVoice();

    public static void AnnounceRestrictionOfAccount()
    {
        WomenAgent.Speak("You're account has been block by the system security", SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
    }

    public static void SayGoodBye()
    {
        WomenAgent.Speak("Goodbye!");
    }

    public static void WelcomeUser(User userToBeWelcomed)
    {
        string Salutation = ConstructWelcomeSpeech(userToBeWelcomed);
        WomenAgent.Speak(Salutation);
    }

    private static string ConstructWelcomeSpeech(User user)
    {
        string salutation = "Welcome ";
        if (user.Gender == "Male")
        {
            salutation += " Mr. ";
        }
        else if (user.Gender == "Female")
        {
            if (user.CivilStatus != null)
            {
                if (user.CivilStatus == "Single")
                    salutation += " Ms. ";
                else
                    salutation += " Mrs. ";
            }
        }
        salutation += user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        return salutation;
    }

    public static void AnnounceMessage(string message)
    {
        WomenAgent.Speak(message);
    }
}
```

and you can read more about SpeechLib in MSDN.

another thing you should also include Microsoft speech lib 5.0 as a reference in you're project. :)

Comment: Wow this is allot of sample? thanks in advance i like you're answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Text-to-speech is built into the .Net Framework 4 without needing to reference any external .dlls, using the [System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) class. It doesn't sound that great on XP, but better on Vista and 7. It's simple to use too:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    synth.Speak("hello");
}
```